# StackedWidget does not works properly

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have the following code snipet in my program.
I was about to use a stacked widget as my central widget.
The class Ui_purchase is a class which is created by qt designer.
When I run this program I get the mainwindow with a small portion of puchase widget in it like in the picture.

[image]

I need main window with all the contents of purchase window in it.

```
class UISuperMarket(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('MASS Supermarket')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('res/images/icon.png'))
        self.centralWidget = QStackedWidget(self)

        purchase = QWidget()
        ui = Ui_purchase()
        ui.setupUi(purchase)
        self.centralWidget.addWidget(purchase)
        self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(purchase)

        self.setupMenuBar()
        self.show()
```

Comment: add `self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)`

Comment: thank you @eyllanesc.really i had not noticed that

Comment: Also, [`centralWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) is an existing function of QMainWindow, so you should not overwrite that attribute (even if that function is rarely used, but that's not the point).

Comment: thank you for your information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)` statement helped me to come out of the problem.Thanks to @eyllanesc for your kindfull information.

The stacked widget `centralWidget` has been changed to another variable name. I was not actually knowing that there exist a method `centralWidget()` in `QMainWindow`.Thanks to @musicamante for your information.